# APIController "Executed" method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

In an **`ApiController`** action I need to close a connection to a database as soon as the action is finished executing.

Under a controller I override `OnActionExecuted` to accomplish this.

How would I accomplish this under an `ApiController` action?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could override the [`ExecuteAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return base
        .ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith(t => 
        {
            // the controller action has finished executing, 
            // your custom code could come here ...

            return t.Result;
        });
}
```

Comment: @Darin where can I find the filtercontext.Exception?                         using (_session){if (_session == null) return;
if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
return;
if (controllerContext.Request.Exception != null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                            else
                                _session.Transaction.Commit();
                        }

Comment: I dont want to commit my transaction if there is an error in the pipelines.... controllerContext.Request.Exception is invalid, where can I get hold of the Exception?

Comment: @Haroon, inspect the `t` argument that is passed to the `ContinueWith` anonymous method. You will find what you are looking there.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thanks - in the code above I cannot use the code return; compiler error (return a HtpResponseMessage required) what would I do. All I want my code to do is save changes if there are no exceptions...

Comment: @Haroon, why do you want to return anything? The API controller action has finished executing at this stage and all you need to do is commit or rollback your transaction.

Comment: I found this very usefull!