# custom caching policy not applied for api response in web-api-2/owin

Tags: angularjs, caching, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am just starting with web-api 2 and stumbled upon : how to set caching settings. I have custom `caching-message-handler` like below (simplified for SO post)

```
public class CachingMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private void SetCachingPolicy(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100),
        };
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base
            .SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;
                if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get) SetCachingPolicy(response);
                return response;
            }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and I have various hello-world HttpGet api's

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get1()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
        response.Content = new StringContent("Hello World 1", Encoding.Unicode);
        return response;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get2()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World 2");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get2_1()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World 2");
        response.Headers.CacheControl = null;
        return response;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public OkNegotiatedContentResult<string> Get3()
    {
        return Ok("Hello World 3");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get4()
    {
        return "Hello World 4";
    }
```

but the `caching-message-handler` is applied only for `Get1` api, for all other `Get2/3/4` api's, it seems some default caching setting is used. Below is the response in postman

[image]

Can someone please explain this behavior!!! why is caching only applied for `Content-Type : text/plain` and not for `application/json`

Comment: you're expecting `no-cache`. Why do you need `max-age` to be more than 0?

Comment: `If a request includes the no-cache directive, it SHOULD NOT include min-fresh, max-stale, or max-age.`: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4

Comment: @KhanhTO even If i keep only max-age, thats still not getting reflected in API response in POSTMAN. But the `custom : 123` is getting reflected, then why the cache settings are ignored :(

Comment: What if you try: `task.Result.Content.Headers.CacheControl`

Comment: try replacing `new CacheControlHeaderValue` with `new CacheControlHeaderValue()` (missing `()`)

Comment: one more thing, you should not use `GetAwaiter()`, it should be used by the compiler instead of application code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx . Try  `return task.ContinueWith(() => ` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428500/apicontroller-executed-method. That could also the problem.

Comment: you question is tagged with OWIN. Do you have any middleware running after web api that happens to override the `cache-control` header?

Comment: @KhanhTO i changed the code as per your comments, but still getting the same response.. no change in Cache-Control header, as expected. Why I expected no change, because I tried it with ActionFilterAttibute `OnActionExecuted` (without async) and that gave me the same behavior. also `()` this is not needed if you are initializing the object, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @KhanhTO I am using only the web-api part. so no other middleware should change it. but somehow i think the cache-control settings is getting changed, because the `custom : 123` is making it to client side

Comment: @KhanhTO check the edit, found something, which completely changed the question

Answer (score 2):

I use angular and WebAPI with owin to build app too, and I have a custom cache filter too, but I use `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` instead of `DelegatingHandler` , and it works for all response types, here is my custom cache filter code:

```
public class NoCacheFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute {

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Request.Method == System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get && actionExecutedContext.Response != null) {
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue {
                NoCache = true, NoStore = true, MustRevalidate = true,
                //MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)
            };
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Pragma.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("no-cache"));
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response.Content != null) {
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

I register the filter in the `Configure` method like this:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Filters.Add(new NoCacheFilter());
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

I think maybe you should try to use `ActionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: actually I already tried it, but still will give it a try with your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header at the backend. CORS returns certain response headers, so you need to tell it to return any other custom headers.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: your-custom-cache-header-1, your-custom-cache-header-2, any-other-headers
```

**Update**

Since postman returns the same results, so it is not angular-related issue. It all resides on the server logic. Try to debug the lifecycle of  `text/plain` and `application/json` requests. That might give you an idea why certain headers are not being set for `application/json` requests.

Comment: i have `access-control-expose-header : *`

Comment: It is `access-control-expose-headers` with "s". And I am not sure it would work with "*". Set it to return a custom headers instead of "*".

Comment: Looks like i am not allowed to type stars in comments :). So, replace "STAR" with string header names.

Comment: with/without `s`, its generated by webapi, so I dont really expect typo issue there. btw, why should names work and not `*` ?

Comment: For security reasons some headers do not work with `*` while `useCredentials` set to `true`.

Comment: how can I set useCredentials to false, we do not use cookies anyways, so I can set that to false, I have created a custom policy but that is not working as expected... would be great if you can provide any sample code.. should i write a separate question for that?

Comment: It should fe `false` by default. To change the value use this `app.config( function($httpProvider) { $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false; });`

Comment: i thought it should be set on server side and not client, :(

Comment: wanted to try your solution but facing another problem, can you please [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345935/custom-cors-policy-not-working)

Comment: it should not be the problem. We need CORS only for cross-domain requests. In the picture of the question, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers : *` should allow all headers.

Comment: @entre; where do you set `application/json` or `text/plain` in code? Do you want to deliver some pages as `json` and some as `plain text`?

Comment: no ways.. thats just an observation, I am not adding any custom formatter on server side. the Conect-Type is sent from angular-side.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should disable caching from server side. But since you tagged `angularjs` & you want to disable caching globally - you can do it like below

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get)  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```