# custom cors policy not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

i have a custom cors policy like below, where I am setting support-credentials to false

```
public class CorsProviderFactory : ICorsPolicyProviderFactory
{
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx

    public ICorsPolicyProvider GetCorsPolicyProvider(
        HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return new CorsPolicyProviderCustom();
    }

    public class CorsPolicyProviderCustom : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider
    {
        private readonly CorsPolicy _policy;

        public CorsPolicyProviderCustom()
        {
            // Create a CORS policy.
            _policy = new CorsPolicy
            {
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                AllowAnyOrigin = true,
                SupportsCredentials = false
            };

            // Magic line right here
            _policy.Origins.Add("*");
            _policy.Methods.Add("*");
        }

        public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_policy);
        }
    }
}
```

and used it like :

```
    public static HttpConfiguration Register()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory(new CorsProviderFactory());
        config.EnableCors();

       .................
 }
```

but even then in the postman response i see, support-credentials as true

[image]

how can I get support-credentials as false, the breakpoint does reaches to the custom policy part, so why is it that its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you can not use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentails` with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*`.

You must specify the exact domain(s) in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, OR set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentails` to `false`.

Comment: if you see the code, i am explicitly setting it to false... still in chrome console (as shown in the last picture) it is coming as true, why?

Comment: actually i dont code for asp.net, so i cant help you setting the header server-side.